# Can someone explain this number = 80; number = (int)math.sqrt(number++) ; number = 8?

Tags: java, math.sqrt

```
int number; 
number = 80; 

number = (int)math.sqrt(number++) 
System.out.println(number)
```

This is the above code. I am new to programming and have a decent under standing of mathematics.

I am aware the SQRT is 8. However in this case i am confused why the answer is not 9.

I am aware of the ++VAR AND VAR++ and how it can affect the answer however given that the PLUS is above the print code i am confused why one is not added to the eight then the number 9 is printed.

Comment: `8.944...` becomes `8` when casted to `int`. This has nothing to do with the actual printing with `println()`. You are saving this value in the variable `number`, and **then** incrementing it. The increment never gets saved to `number`.

Comment: Hello, Its joe, Thanks for helping me understand this concept. Regaurds, joe

Answer (score 3):

The update `++` makes to `number` in the right-hand operand of the assignment is overwritten by assigning the result of the overall expression back to `number`.

This is covered by [JLS§15.26.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1). Here's what happens in that assignment expression:

1. The left-hand side is determined to be a variable
2. The right-hand side of the assignment expression is evaluated:

   1. The value `80` is read from `number`
   2. `number` is incremented to 81 (this doesn't matter)
   3. `math.sqrt` is called with the value `80` read above
   4. The result of `math.sqrt` is converted to an `int`
3. The result from #2 above (`8`) is stored in `number`

Note the order of Steps 2.1 and 2.2 above. That's because you've used the postfix `number++`. The order would be reversed (and the result different) if you used `++number`.

The `++` on `number` on the right-hand side has no effect whatsoever on the result of the expression. (In Java. In some other langauges, this would be considered Undefined Behavior allowing a compiler to do whatever it wants.)

In particular (since you mentioned expecting to get the value `9`), the `++` doesn't get applied after the result of the assignment is stored in `number`. It gets applied immediately after reading the value of `number` when passing it into `math.sqrt`.

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Comment: In simpler terms, the side-effect is an integral part of the evaluation of `i++`. As soon as you're using the result of the expression, the side-effect is already applied.

Comment: Hello, Thanks very much for your incredibility informative answer. Thanks, Joe

Answer (score 1):

`number++` postincrements, meaning the expression is evaluated to 80 inside the square root function.

Square root of 80 is strictly less than 9 so its integer conversion (done with `(int)`) is 8.

Comment: Hello, Thanks alot for your reply. Thanks Joe

Answer (score 1):

```
number = (int)math.sqrt(number++) ,
```

Here First expression is evaluated,then number is increased, thats' why.

If you change it to

```
number = (int)math.sqrt(++number) ,
```

then it will work

Comment: Hello, Thanks very much for your reply. This was an answer which confused me on a past paper for my Uni course. So i was mainly just concerned with why i got the result i did rather than fixing the script. However thanks a lot for your reply joe

Answer (score 0):

In java, post increment effects the variable when the expression is evaluated, not after the statement is run. So the variable gets incremented to 81, previous value 80 is passed to sqrt, and finally gets assigned 8.